# Create a fiscal calendar in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a fiscal calendar in which the fiscal year starts July 1 and a week is defined as Monday to Sunday.

But for example; if the 1st day in a week in a month is a Saturday, then Saturday to Sunday will be seen as 1 week in that month and the new week starts on Monday and ends on Sunday and so on.

See sample of the table I want to create below:

[image]

- Period refers to the months of the fiscal year.
- Week is number of weeks in that month.
- Start date(week start date) is the day the week began
- End date(week end date) is the day the week ended.
- Day of week is the dates between the start date and end date.
- Year

I am thinking that I need a procedure that maybe takes the first day of the fiscal year then iterates through all the days of the year adding the columns start and end date, week number, period and year the day belongs to.

Comment: "Week is number of weeks in that month."   Do you mean weeks in that year?    Thinking of a week as belonging to a month gets problematic.

Comment: I get what you saying..if that would yield the same result that we could take that route @TabAlleman

Comment: Well it wouldn't yield the same result.   In one case the week column would start over at 1 at some arbitrary point every month.  In the other, the week column will go up to 52 and start over at 1 the next fiscal year.

Comment: Indeed @TabAlleman, the former is what we are trying to achieve. Which is part of the problem.

Comment: You need to include your rule for when the week should reset to 1 then.   And also what happens to the EndDate column when the month changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yet another option.  This will generate 50 years is 0.703 seconds

**Example**

```
Set DateFirst  1

Declare @Date1 date = '2017-07-01'
Declare @Date2 date = '2019-06-30'


Select Period    = Dense_Rank() over (Partition By FY Order By FM)
      ,Week      = Dense_Rank() over (Partition By FY,FM Order By FW)
      ,StartDate = Min(D) over (Partition By FY,FM,FW )
      ,EndDate   = Max(D) over (Partition By FY,FM,FW )
      ,DayOfWeek = D
      ,Year      = FY
 From (
        Select FY = DatePart(Year,@Date1)-1+sum(case when convert(varchar(5),@Date1,101)=convert(varchar(5),D,101) then 1 else 0 end) over (Order By D)
              ,FM = sum(case when DatePart(Day,D)=DatePart(Day,@Date1) then 1 else 0 end) over (Order By D)
              ,FW = sum(case when DatePart(WeekDay,D)=1 then 1 else 0 end) over (Order By D)
              ,D
         From (
                Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,@Date1,@Date2)+1) 
                       D  = DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),@Date1) 
                 From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2
              ) A1
      ) A
 Order By D
```

Comment: This is a simpler solution, however, the week does not reset when a new period starts. It only resets in a new fiscal year starts

Comment: @CastellJames I assumed Week of Year.  Easy change for Week on Month

Comment: ahhh by just changing the `FY` TO `FM` in the outer select statement correct?

Comment: @CastellJames See updated answer ... This one will reset Week # and Beg/End with each FM

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a procedure, but some functions can be handy.

First of, keep in mind, that some date-time functions have a dependency on @@DATEFIRST. To make your code independent of this setting, you can have a function which normalizes the day number.

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNormalizedWeekDay
(
      @inputDate DATE
    , @dateFirst TINYINT = 1
)
RETURNS SMALLINT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN ((DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @inputDate) + @@DATEFIRST - 1 - @dateFirst) % 7) + 1;
END
```

In this, you can tell which day you want to use and calculates the result based on that. Will be handy to determine if a day is Sunday for example.

If I understand you properly, you want a week function which behaves similarly to the built-in function, but treats 1st of July as the first day of year.

Something like this should do it:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getFiscalWeekNumber
(
      @inputDate        DATE
    , @firstFiscalMonth TINYINT = 7
    , @dateFirst        TINYINT = 1
)
RETURNS TINYINT
AS
BEGIN
    /* NULL Input handling. */
    IF (@inputDate IS NULL) BEGIN
        RETURN NULL
    END

    DECLARE @inputDateWeekDay        TINYINT = getNormalizedWeekDay(@inputDate, @dateFirst);
    DECLARE @inputWeekStartDate      DATE    = DATEADD(DAY, -(@inputDateWeekDay-1), @inputDate);

    DECLARE @firstDayOfYear          DATE    = DATEFROMPARTS(getFiscalYear(@inputDate, @firstFiscalMonth), @firstFiscalMonth, 1);
    DECLARE @firstWeekStartDate      DATE    = @firstDayOfYear;
    DECLARE @weekDayOfFirstDayOfYear TINYINT = getNormalizedWeekDay(@firstDayOfYear, @dateFirst);

    -- The day is between the first day of year and the beginning of the second week -> 1st (partial) week for non-iso style
    IF (@inputDate >= @firstDayOfYear AND @inputDate < DATEADD(DAY, -(@weekDayOfFirstDayOfYear-1), DATEADD(DAY, 7, @firstWeekStartDate))) BEGIN
        RETURN 1;
    END

    -- Adjust the first day of the weeks to match with @dateFirst.
    SET @firstWeekStartDate = DATEADD(DAY, -(@weekDayOfFirstDayOfYear-1), @firstWeekStartDate);

    RETURN (DATEDIFF(DAY, @firstWeekStartDate, @inputWeekStartDate) / 7) + 1;
END
```

Please keep in mind, that some of the functions may not exist in older versions of SQL Server, I am using SQL Server 2016.

Comment: what is `calendar` referencing?

Comment: ahh, sorry, I just rewrote one of my scripts and forgot that schema name in it.

Comment: so that should be changed to the schema the function is in..i.e given that when I ran the script it appeared in the master schema..I should changed it to that?

Comment: it is your decision where you put these functions and your table. I have a set of tables and scripts what I am using for these kind of stuff and they usually live in the calendar schema.

Answer (score 0):

You can create this table using a `common table expression` (`cte` for short) tally table.  This involves manually specifying the first 10 rows (the `select t from values...` bit) and then `cross join`ing this to itself several times in a second `cte` to exponentially create more rows.  Because I have 6 cross joins (the `t t1, t t2, t t3...` part) I am generating a million rows (`10^6`), then working out how many I actually need in the `top` clause and then using `row_number` to generate an iterative list that is added as days to your period start date.

The output of this is a table of dates you can apply functions to, that will even work across multiple financial years.  I would recommend you use this to create a `Dates` lookup table rather than running every single time:

```
declare @DateStart date = '20160701'
       ,@DateEnd   date = '20170630';

with t(t) as (select t from (values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) t(t))
    ,d(d) as (select top(datediff(d,@DateStart,@DateEnd)+1) dateadd(d,row_number() over (order by (select null))-1,@DateStart) from t t1,t t21,t t31,t t4,t t5,t t6)
select ((dense_rank() over (order by dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,d),0)) - 1) % 12) + 1 as [Period]

      ,dense_rank() over (partition by dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,d),0)
                          order by case when dateadd(d,1-datepart(dw,d),d) < dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,d),0)
                                        then dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,d),0)
                                        else dateadd(d,1-datepart(dw,d),d)
                                        end) as [Week]

      ,case when dateadd(d,1-datepart(dw,d),d) < dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,d),0)
            then dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,d),0)
            else dateadd(d,1-datepart(dw,d),d)
            end as StartDate

      ,case when dateadd(d,7-datepart(dw,d),d) > dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,d)+1,0)
            then dateadd(d,-1,dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,d)+1,0))
            else dateadd(d,7-datepart(dw,d),d)
            end as EndDate

      ,d as DayOfWeek
      ,year(d) as [Year]
from d
order by d;
```

Output:

```
+--------+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------+------+
| Period | Week |        StartDate        |         EndDate         | DayOfWeek  | Year |
+--------+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------+------+
|      1 |    1 | 2016-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 2016-07-02 00:00:00.000 | 2016-07-01 | 2016 |
|      1 |    1 | 2016-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 2016-07-02 00:00:00.000 | 2016-07-02 | 2016 |
|      1 |    2 | 2016-07-03 00:00:00.000 | 2016-07-09 00:00:00.000 | 2016-07-03 | 2016 |
|      1 |    2 | 2016-07-03 00:00:00.000 | 2016-07-09 00:00:00.000 | 2016-07-04 | 2016 |
|      1 |    2 | 2016-07-03 00:00:00.000 | 2016-07-09 00:00:00.000 | 2016-07-05 | 2016 |
|      1 |    2 | 2016-07-03 00:00:00.000 | 2016-07-09 00:00:00.000 | 2016-07-06 | 2016 |
|      1 |    2 | 2016-07-03 00:00:00.000 | 2016-07-09 00:00:00.000 | 2016-07-07 | 2016 |
|      1 |    2 | 2016-07-03 00:00:00.000 | 2016-07-09 00:00:00.000 | 2016-07-08 | 2017 |
.
.
.
|     12 |    5 | 2017-06-25 00:00:00.000 | 2017-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 2017-06-28 | 2017 |
|     12 |    5 | 2017-06-25 00:00:00.000 | 2017-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 2017-06-29 | 2017 |
|     12 |    5 | 2017-06-25 00:00:00.000 | 2017-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 2017-06-30 | 2017 |
+--------+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------+------+
```