# Get value from a joined table with no value in primary table

Tags: sql, sql-server

The query shown below is just about right, but I need to have a row for each fiscal Id, i.e. in the output shown below, there needs to be a new row after row 4 with data (screen shot below)

The query I'm using is:

```
    SELECT a.companyId,a.profitCenterID,a.coaID,a.fiscalId,
       COALESCE(SUM(a.amount * -1),0) amount,
       twelveMo = (
       SELECT COALESCE(SUM(amount * -1), 0)
       FROM gl a1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal f ON a1.fiscalId=f.Id
       WHERE  
           a1.companyId      =  a.companyId AND
           a1.profitCenterId =  a.profitCenterId AND
           a1.coaId          =  a.coaId AND
           f.Id              >  a.fiscalId - 12 AND 
           f.Id              <= a.fiscalId
        )
    FROM gl a
    INNER JOIN coa c ON c.Id=a.coaId AND c.statementType=4
    GROUP BY companyId,profitCenterId,coaId,a.fiscalId  
    ORDER BY companyId,profitCenterId,coaId,a.fiscalId
```

[image: Desired query result]

Comment: Tip: Don't use `SELECT` subqueries inside the projection clause of an  outer `SELECT` (it's a SQL code smell). Consider refactoring your query as a `FROM`-subquery.

Comment: You need a calendar/count table of some sort which has all the rows you require which you then join on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a fiscal calendar in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45084425/how-to-create-a-fiscal-calendar-in-t-sql)

Comment: Sample data would really help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your sample datas and your schema's, so I've just added my query on the top of your's.

```
;WITH CTE_NUM_TEMP AS 
(
    SELECT 1 AS Fiscal
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Fiscal+1 FROM CTE_NUM_TEMP
    WHERE Fiscal+1<=100
)

SELECT ISNULL(Der.companyId,1) AS companyId,ISNULL(Der.profitCenterID,1) AS profitCenterID,
ISNULL(Der.coaID,40000) AS coaID,IIF(twelveMo IS NULL,LAG(twelveMo,1) OVER(ORDER BY Fiscal),twelveMo) AS twelveMo
FROM CTE_NUM_TEMP AS Num
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT a.companyId,a.profitCenterID,a.coaID,a.fiscalId,
    COALESCE(SUM(a.amount * -1),0) amount,
    twelveMo = (
    SELECT COALESCE(SUM(amount * -1), 0)
    FROM gl a1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal f ON a1.fiscalId=f.Id
    WHERE  
        a1.companyId      =  a.companyId AND
        a1.profitCenterId =  a.profitCenterId AND
        a1.coaId          =  a.coaId AND
        f.Id              >  a.fiscalId - 12 AND 
        f.Id              <= a.fiscalId
    )
    FROM gl a
    INNER JOIN coa c ON c.Id=a.coaId AND c.statementType=4
    GROUP BY companyId,profitCenterId,coaId,a.fiscalId  
)AS Der
ON Num.Fiscal=Der.fiscalId
```