# How to filter by fiscal months in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am looking to filter out or create a new column that segments my data into fiscal month. I have a table like the one pictured below.

Every fiscal month begins on the 26 and ends on the 25 day. (ex: 1/26/21 - 2/25/21)

I want to count the total numbers for each fiscal month vs calendar month. What's the best way to do this?

[image]

Comment: People won't see that image. You'll have a better chance of getting a good answer if you edit the question to paste the sample data as _formatted_ text.

Comment: Sounds like you need a calendar table, with a start and end date for each month

Answer (score 1):

You should check out this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45084425/create-a-fiscal-calendar-in-t-sql) question.

From that it seems like you'd have to create a custom date range for the fiscal month and then a window partition to group on items within the date range.